# Tail -c linux command implementation in C

Tags: c, buffer, implementation, tail

I need to write a tail in C language, where the input stream will be the argument in the console. The function should cut n characters from the input data. The command calling the program should be "echo" an example text "| ./a.out 4" - that is, the last 4 characters of the given input will be printed.
Unfortunately, my function does not print anything to me.
Thanks in advance. If there are any other, smarter solutions then I am open to suggestions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define MAXLINES 100


char* tailFunction (const char* argv[])
{
        char* buf, data;
        int n = 0, i =0;
        buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINES);
        n = atoi(argv[0]+1);
        while (data != EOF)
        {
            data = getc(stdin);
            buf[i] = data;
            i++;

        }
        int x = strlen(buf) - n;
        for ( ; x < strlen(buf) ; x++)
        {
            printf("%c", buf[x]);
        }

        free(buf);
        return 0;


}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (argv < MAXLINES)
    {
    tailFunction(argv);
    return 0;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

Comment: You should try to compile in debug mode (`-g` on gcc,clang) with not optimizations (`-O0` on gcc,clang) and run you program using valgrind

Comment: You should start by enabling compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` on gcc or clang, also set the compiler to optimize `-O3`). If you can, enable `-fsanitize=address` and other sanitizers, once the code compiles without warnings.

Comment: there is no memory allocation. I do not quite know why, if it's malloc.

Comment: @Sheepp How do you know there is no memory allocation?

Comment: @EOF From valgrind. There is an information about 0 allocs and 0 frees.

Comment: How are you compiling? `argv < MAXLINES` is a comparison between a pointer and an integer. What is the exit code of the program? If it is `255`, then your code is probably returning `-1` from `main`.

Comment: @Sheepp You should not run the program under valgrind until the compile succeeds without warnings, with warnings enabled.

Comment: @ljeabmreosn Yes, I noticed that. I pasted the previous version.